# Count Number of Each Month in Column of dates in Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google sheet with a column of dates.  I would like to get a total for each month, so that I can see how many of the dates are January, February, March, etc.  This formula does not work (**Dates** is the name of range):

```
=COUNTIF(Dates,Month=1)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Following the logic of your proposition, the error is that `MONTH()` returns an integer, not an array. You can add `ARRAYFORMULA()` to do the job :

```
=COUNTIF( ARRAYFORMULA( MONTH( Dates ) ), "=2" )
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally devised the correct search term for [Google help](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/N9Ip5ZzweVQ)

```
=sumproduct(month(Dates)=2)
```