# Google Sheets: create bar chart to show daily total count of all persons working in each day of a month

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have rows of employees with their start-dates(column W2:W) and end-dates(column X2:X) showing when they are working. If an employee is working more than once they will have multiple rows showing start and end dates for each period of time they are working.

I wish to end up with a bar chart showing the days of a month along the x-axis, and the count of workers that are working shown along the y-axis. The formula should tally the total workers that are in on each date and then present it as a bar.

This creates two issues:
1. calculate the total count of all workers that are in on any given day
2. Do it for each day of the month

The relevant month to be used is stored in the cell S12

(I have not yet solved issue 1. so have not even looked at issue 2.)
Attempts to resolve the first issue got me this far.
This works on a single row:

```
=COUNTIFS(S12, ">="&W2, S12, "<="&X2)
```

But unfortunately this does not work when applied to columns:

```
=COUNTIFS(S12, ">="&W2:W, S12, "<="&X2:X)
```

Can someone point me in the right direction. Should I be using some other formula?

Comment: Why tag excel when you are using googlesheets?

Comment: because the formula is similar and it reaches a larger scope of viewers where exactly the same problem would be experienced the same and the solution is likely v similar.

Comment: Have you checked on here? see https://stackoverflow.com/q/35250097/4961700

Comment: @Solar I have been messing about with ARRAYFORMULA and SUM and managed to get something working for the first part, just checking it now, but not in the format used in the link, no.

Answer (score 2):

For the formula, may be you can change the countif, in google sheet:

```
=COUNTIF(W2:W,"<=" & S12) + COUNTIF(X2:X,">=" & S12)
```

With ArrayFormula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(countif({W2:W}<=S12,"=true") + countif({X2:X}>=S12,"=true" ))
```

Comment: not sure it covers it fully. That way round might work, but I found a solution that definitely worked using ARRAYFORMULA and SUM together.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was a mixture of ARRAYFORMULA , SUM, and COUNTIFS.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIFS(S12, ">="&{W2:W}, S12, "<="&{X2:X})))
```

For the second half of the issue - which required getting it into a monthly bar chart - I just populated a column of cells for each day of any month (1-31). My example below also required I be able to change the month and year to alter the chart. In the formula below I used another cell for the year (S1) and took the Month itself from a drop downlist (1-12 stored in S2).

My final working formula (where R column was the day of the month, S1 was the year (in date form), and S2 the month as a dropdown list):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIFS(DATE(YEAR($S$1),$S$2,R2), ">="&{$W$2:W}, DATE(YEAR($S$1),$S$2,R2), "<="&{$X$2:X})))
```

with this formula dragged down the column beside the month column (R) it provided all I needed to make the chart from it.

Comment: I have tested =ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIFS(S12, ">="&{W2:W}, S12, "<="&{X2:X}))), the result is same with =arrayformula(COUNTIFS({W2:W}, "<=" & S12, {X2:X}, ">=" & S12 )), and same to with =COUNTIFS(W2:W, "<=" & S12, X2:X,">=" & S12) if both criteria are true, the result will be increased by 1. For example if data in rows W = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), X = {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1) , and S12=2 so the result for all formula will be 3, because for three row {2,3,4} will give W={0,1,2} <= (S12={12}} and X={9,8,7} >= (S2={2})